# Is it possible to have each combobox in a grid have a different itemsource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a WPF application that has a datagrid.  One of the columns in the datagrid has a combobox.  I want each instance of the combobox to have it's own itemsource.  Is this possible?

Comment: What kind of objects are you binding to? Usually when a DataGrid has rows of objects, they tend to be the same objects. Please just explain the kind of data you would like to put in the comboboxes and how each row is related but different. The best solution might be to not even use a datagrid, or to change the way input is captured for each row

Answer (score 1):

yes. this is possible.

just set the ItemSource property to whatever collection you want.  You can even databind it, if you like.

here is a nice article on comboboxes and databinding on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301678/Step-by-Step-WPF-Data-Binding-with-Comboboxes)

Comment: He is asking about ComboBoxes in a DataGrid. I think he wants the rows autogenerated with the ComboBox in each row to have a different datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is Possible.

Just find the combobox in "RowDataound" event of grid.
and bind each combobox there with different datasource.